# A term in a loop contains itself

Tags: r, loops

```
y <- rnorm(5)
X <- matrix(rnorm(15),5)
b <- rep(0, 3)
e <- y - X%*%b

w <- rep(0, 3)

A <- c(1,2,1)  

for(i in 1:10){
  for(j in 1:3){
    e <- e + X[,j]*b[j]
    xe <- sum(X[,j]*e)
    w[j] <- xe
    b[j] <- xe - (A%*%w - 1.5)
    e <- e - X[,j]*b[j]
  }
}
```

This is a dummy code that generate vector `b`. The problem here is that one of the vector in the loop is `w` which depends all the terms in `b`: 
This `w` vector effects `b` as a vector not term by term. But the terms in `w` also depend on `b[j]`'s. 
In the inner loop `w` vector is

```
1.78787 0.00000 0.00000         # first iteration
1.787870 -1.231099  0.000000    # second iteration
1.787870 -1.231099  7.507026    # Third iteration
```

respectively, for the first iteration over `i`.

According to theory, `w` should be in the form of third iteration not in the forms with zeros. This means for `b[1]`, `w` has three zeros, for `b[2]`, `w` has two zeros etc, but I need to use the same `w` for all `b[j]`'s.

I hope, I explained it properly. Maybe this is simple, but I'm confused.

What is the best way to code this situation: The iterations to estimate `b` depend all the terms in `b`?

A summary for math behind this is as following. `b[j]`'s are iterated until convergence.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be an optimization problem? I'm afraid you don't express your question very clearly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added a mathematical explanation for that to clarify.